# Ajax statuscode 503 is not being fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, api

I am currently trying to interact with the API from https://developer.accuweather.com/

I have gotten it to work, but I am currently on their "Free Trial" plan, where I am limited to 50 requests a day. When the limit is reached, their server will respond with http code 503 unauthorized. I want perform an action when I get a 503 code from their API.

This is my code:

```
//Sends ajax requests
async function ajaxReq(url) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "GET",
            statusCode: {
                503: function(data) {
                    console.log("oopsie doopsie 503");
                }
            },
            success: function(res) {
                resolve(res);
            },
        });
    });
}
```

I'm using statuscode callback to handle the error as many others have suggested, but it does not fire. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the expected 503 response?

Comment: @Don'tPanic How do I test this?

Comment: Check your browser's devtools, look at the network tab - you should see the AJAX request, and the response.